# importXML from a specified date onward

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import this xml in Google Sheets but I want the feed to start at 1980-01-02, which is a date listed in the XML.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fKqU.png)

Comment: whats the url??

Comment: https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/V80691311/xml